# Does here $R$ is the set of all possible remainders when integers are divided by $m$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Set $\mathbb Z/m \Bbb Z$ is called the set of Congruence Classes modulo $m$(also called Residue class modulo $m$).

Now,$\mathbb Z/m \Bbb Z=${$0+\mathbb Z/m \Bbb Z$,$1+\mathbb Z/m \Bbb Z$,$2+\mathbb Z/m \Bbb Z$,...,$(m-1)+\mathbb Z/m \Bbb Z$}.

The set $R=${$r_1,r_2,r_3,...,r_m$} is called a complete set of Residue modulo $m$ if $r_1,r_2,r_3,...,r_m$  are pairwise incongrent modulo $m$.

> **Does here $R$ is the set of all possible remainders when integers are divided by $m$?If $Yes$,then the complete set of residues modulo $m$ should be {$0,1,2,3,...,(m-1)$}**.

Considering it as a true result ,the complete set of residue modulo $7$ will be {$0,1,2,3,4,5,6$},but it is not so.(It is {$0,2,4,6,8,10,12$}).

I think i've understood this concept in a wrong way.I need to know where i'm wrong.

If anyone have different viewpoint  for this,plese share it with me.

> **NOTE:I do not have any any background for number theory.**

Thank you

Comment: By your definition both are complete sets of residues. An equivalent definition is that every integer is congruent to exactly one element of the set. Don't confuse "residue' with "remainder". Remainders are the least nonegative elements in the residue class,

Comment: @BillDubuque:Yoy mean to say, every integer  $t$ is congruent modulo $m$ to some integer $r_i \in R$?

Comment: @BillDubuque:i think,it is the point where i got confused.

Comment: Yes, but congruent to one *and only one* $\,r_\in R\,$

Comment: @BillDubuque:What is the difference b/w remainder & Residue?

Comment: @BillDubuque:As the set {$0,1,2,3,...,(m-1)$} is called set of residue modulo $m$,which is also the set of all possible remainders when integers are divided by $m$.

Comment: Usually (but not always) *the* remainder refers to a canonical representative chosen from each residue class, which is usually chosen to be the least nonnegative residue (just like we usually choose the least terms rep for each fraction in its equivalence class of equal fractions).

Comment: @BillDubuque:You mean remainder is least non-negative element of each residue class?

Comment: Yes, that is by far the most common canonical choice or representative.

Comment: @BillDubuque:If we consider 15,then $15\equiv 1(mod 7)$,but $1$ is not within the complete set of residue modulo 7,{$0,2,4,6,8,10,12$}?

Comment: But $\ 15\equiv 8\pmod 7$ and $\,8\in R.\,$ Recall that, by definition $\,a\equiv b\pmod n\iff n\mid a-b\iff a-b = kn\,$ for some integer $\,n.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque:But 1=8 in (modulo 7).

Comment: @BillDubuque:Is the set $R$ unique?

Comment: There are infinitely many complete residue systems since there are infinitely many possibilities to choose as rep for each residue class, e.g. we can choose any element of $\,\{1+km\,:\, k\in\Bbb Z\}\,$ for the rep in $R$ that is $\equiv 1\pmod m$. You might be confusing mod the relation with mod the operator. There are many answers explaining the difference, e.g. [here,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/112490/242)

Answer (score 1):

1. $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is
   $$\{0+m\mathbb{Z},1+m\mathbb{Z},\dots,m-1+m\mathbb{Z}\}$$
2. $R=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}=\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12\}$.
   Because in this context $1$ means
   $$1+7\mathbb{Z}=\{\dots,-13,-6,1,8,15,\dots\}$$
   and equally for all the rest numbers: $0=0+7\mathbb{Z},\;1=1+7\mathbb{Z},\;2=2+7\mathbb{Z},\dots$.
   Therefore, $8=1$, because $1+7\mathbb{Z}=8+7\mathbb{Z}$; $10=3$, because $10+7\mathbb{Z}=3+7\mathbb{Z}$ and $12=5$ because $12+7\mathbb{Z}=5+7\mathbb{Z}$.
   Therefore, both sets $R=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $R=\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12\}$ are complete set of residue modulo $7$