# Multiplicative inverse example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, inverse

Theorem: Multiplicative inverse of x mod m is y with x*y = 1(mod m).

Example: For 4 modulo 7 inverse is 2: 2*4 = 8 = 1(mod 7).

Why 1(mod 7) is 8? I thought mod(1,7) = 1

Comment: $1\equiv8\pmod7$ means $7|1-8$.  With mod as a binary operator (remainder after division), $\mod(1,7)=  1$

Comment: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614931/name-of-mod-or-remainder-operation-in-mathematics/614944#614944) discusses the different mod's and so does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112337/modulo-question/112490#112490)

Comment: $\large\begin{align} &8\equiv 1\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!7}\ \ {\rm means}\ \ \ 7\mid 8-1,\ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ 7  \ {\rm divides}\ 8-1\\[.4em]
&8\bmod 7\, =\, 1\ \ \ \ {\rm means}\ \ \ 8\div 7\ \ {\rm leaves\ remainder}\ = 1\end{align}$ $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two notions of mod, which are related but distinct.

One is a binary operation, which gives a result of two numbers, and is often used in computer science:

$\mod(a,b)$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$.

In that context, $\mod(1,7)=\color{blue}1$ because $1=0\times7+\color{blue}1.$

The other is a relation, often used in mathematics:

$a\equiv b\pmod n$ means $n$ divides $a-b$.

In that context, $1\equiv8\pmod7$, because $7\mid1-8$.